# $5^{2012}+1$ is divisible with $313$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that: $\displaystyle5^{2012}+1$ is divisible with $313$.

What I try and what I know:

$313$ is prime
and I try use the following formula :

$$a^n+b^n=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+\ldots\pm(-1)^{n}b^{n-1})$$

but still nothing. this problem can be solved using a elementary proof because I found it a mathematical magazine for children with the age of 14.

Comment: Note that the formula that you are trying to use is for odd n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$5^4=625\equiv -1\pmod {313}$ as $626=2\cdot313$

So, $5^{2012}=(5^4)^{503}\equiv (-1)^{503}\pmod {313}\equiv-1$

---

Alternatively, $5^4=625=313\cdot2-1$

So,  $5^{2012}=(5^4)^{503}=(313\cdot2-1)^{503}=(313\cdot2)^{513}+\binom {513}1(313\cdot2)^{512}(-1)^1+\cdots+\binom {513}{512}(313\cdot2)(-1)^{512}-1$

Observe that all the except the last is divisible by $313$

So, the remainder i.e.,  $5^{2012} \mod {313}$ is $-1$

Comment: can you give me another solution without using $mod$? thaks, and thanks for the proof .

Comment: @Iuli, please find the edited answer and share your queries, if any .

Comment: it is ok :) thanks :)

Comment: @Iuli: Asking for an argument about divisibility without using modulus is like asking for a salad without any vegetables.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm totally agree with you, but this problem must be done by a  child who didn't learn anything about $mod$.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac {5^{2012} + 1}{626} =\frac {5^{2012} + 1}{5^{4} + 1 }  = \frac {(5^{4})^{503} + 1}{(5^{4}) + 1 } = \frac {a^{n} + b ^n }{a+b}
$$

Where $ a = 5^4  and\ $ $ b =1 \ and\ $ $ n=503 (odd)$

### **Concept** : $ {a^{n} + b ^n } $ is always a multiple of $ a+b\ $ when n is odd

.

so this division gives remainder $0 $.

As $ 626 = 313 *2 $  It should also be divisible by 313 .

hence $ \frac {5^{2012} + 1}{313}  $ gives remainder $ 0 $.

so its divisible by 313 .

Hence proved

Answer (score 1):

$5^{2012}+1=(5^4)^{503}-(-1)^{503}$, thus $5^4-(-1)|5^{20212}+1$ Finally we note that $313|5^4-(-1)$. This is because $5^4-(-1)=626=2(313)$

Answer (score 0):

Just use the fact that $a+b$ divides $a^n+b^n$, if $n$ is odd.

Here $5^4+1=626$ divides $(5^4)^{503}+1^{503}=5^{2012}+1$.